# Query Importrange doesn't import every cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets and want to import every cell in Col16 where Col 3 is not empty to another sheet. So far so good and this is the formula which does exactly that:

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/XYZ";"XYZ!A2:BZ"); "SELECT Col16 WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL"; 0)

The problem is that Col16 contains cells which start with a number and some cells which start with a letter. The cells with a letter are not imported and the cells stay empty.
Any idea how to fix that?

Looking forward to your help! Thank you

Tried to formate the cells to "Plain Text" in the source file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If there are mixed data types in a column, QUERY will only return the most frequent data-type, try casting everything to text using `TO_TEXT`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/XYZ";"XYZ!A2:BZ")); "SELECT Col16 WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL"; 0))`